# How to paint multiple linear regression with 3d flat

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

How to paint multiple linear regression with 3d flat.

I've tried this problem.
I used `plot()` and `plot_surface()`, but it is not correct.

I think that painted multiple linear must be a 3d flat.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

data = read_csv('price data2.csv', sep=',')

xy = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
x_data = xy[0:500, 1:-1]
y_data = xy[0:500, [-1]]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name="bias")

hypothesis = X[0] * W[0] + X[1] * W[1] + b

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)

for step in range(500):
    cost_, hypo_, _ = sess.run([cost, hypothesis, train], feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})

plt.plot(x_data[:, 1], x_data[:, 0], sess.run(W)[0] * x_data[:, 0] + sess.run(W)[1] * x_data[:, 1] + sess.run(b))

#fail
#x0, x1 = np.meshgrid(x_data[:, 0], x_data[:, 1])
#ax.plot_surface(x1, x0, y_data)


plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the observed vs expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example Python code that makes a 3D scatterplot, a 3D surface plot, and a contour plot. You can rotate the 3D images by holding down the mouse button and dragging the plot. This example uses a flat surface equation, but the equation does not have to be flat.

[image: scatter]

[image: surface]

[image: contour]

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, b, c):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    return (a * x) + (y * b) + c


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```